# How does a PR pipeline vary from CI pipeline in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I know this is a basic question but can someone explain with a scenario based on VCS like Git

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "PR" pipeline is just a pipeline that is triggered by a new pull request. It will usually run tests, static analysis, linting, or other checks against the incoming branch as a way to ensure coding standards are met before merging the PR. Azure DevOps will show the progress and result of the build on the PR page as well.

A CI pipeline is usually triggered when a specific branch is changed (perhaps `master` or `develop`). A build is automatically kicked off to run build/tests/static analysis/archiving/etc to ensure the new commits do not break things.

Here is more information from Microsoft that may help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/what-is-continuous-integration

Hope this helps!

Comment: so the PR pipeline would be merged into dev branch once the incoming branch(personal branch) is validated and then the CI pipeline will start since the merge results in change to develop branch?

Comment: Once the pipeline for a pull request is done, thats all it does! :)   

PR pipelines are meant to validate an incoming pull requests changes before the pull request is accepted by a human. This helps catch tests failing or linting failing before a person looks at the diff.